# jQuery detach and appendTo multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, appendto, detach

I want to detach a row when user clicked to a specific button inside row and append it to another table again and again.

My below script detaches and appends the other row once. However it continues toggling classes on following clicks, it doesn't make detach and append. It also cannot update the db.

What is wrong with this snippet?

```
$('.orderHideBtn').on('click',function(){
    var $oid = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    $data = 'a=hideOrder&oid='+$oid[1];
    $.ajax({
        data: $data,
        success: function(msg){
            $('#hbtn-'+$oid[1]).toggleClass("orderHideBtn orderShowBtn").toggleClass('icon-eye-close icon-eye-open').closest('tr').detach().appendTo('#ordersTBody2');
            console.log('#hbtn-'+$oid[1]);
        }
    });
});
$('.orderShowBtn').on('click',function(){
    var $oid = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    $data = 'a=showOrder&oid='+$oid[1];
    $.ajax({
        data: $data,
        success: function(msg){
            $('#hbtn-'+$oid[1]).toggleClass("orderShowBtn orderHideBtn").toggleClass('icon-eye-open icon-eye-close').closest('tr').detach().appendTo('#ordersTBody1');
            console.log('#hbtn-'+$oid[1]);
        }
    });
});
```

These are HTML buttons:

```
<span id="hbtn-{$o.orderID}" class="orderHideBtn icon-eye-close"></span>
```

and

```
<span id="hbtn-{$o.orderID}" class="orderShowBtn icon-eye-open"></span>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of detach() here? Are you looking for .clone() instead?

Comment: I want to remove row from active orders table and append to passive orders. Or vice versa

Comment: you don't need to use detach() as appendTo() will already move element. You should provide a jsfiddle which reproduce your issue

Comment: Still, it doesn't append on second or following clicks. I am preparing jsfiddle now

Comment: I just see that your issue seems to be that a selector relative to an handler is not reevaluated each time the handler is fired. It is bound to element and stay as it. The way you can solve it is to use delegation: `$(document).on('click','.orderHideBtn',function(){...});` and same logic for other handler

Comment: Could you please write that as answer. Thank you. My old .live() habbits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are switching class and selector relative to hanlder is not re-evaluated, you should delegate event, e.g:

```
$(document.body).on('click','.orderHideBtn',function(){
    var $oid = this.id.split('-');
    $data = 'a=hideOrder&oid='+$oid[1];
    $.ajax({
        data: $data,
        success: function(msg){
            $('#hbtn-'+$oid[1]).toggleClass("orderHideBtn orderShowBtn").toggleClass('icon-eye-close icon-eye-open').closest('tr').appendTo('#ordersTBody2');
            console.log('#hbtn-'+$oid[1]);
        }
    });
});
```

I removed detach() method because, as i'm aware of, it is useless here.